# Date coming through as Character, need to fix in R

Tags: r, date

I have imported a .csv file into R. The files has several columns (I simplified to 4), and two of these columns--`assigned` and `completed`--should be dates, however, they are coming in as "character". I need them to be read as dates.

I have spent several hours searching and trying different things but cannot not find a solution. This is what the data looks like (first 3 rows, I have 5K rows total):

```
       id assigned completed score
1:     54 11/10/16  11/10/16     0
2:     54 11/21/16  11/21/16     7
3:     54  1/26/17   1/26/17    11


> summary(data_subset)
       id        assigned          completed        
 Min.   :   54   Length:5991        Length:5991       
 1st Qu.: 1375   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median : 1910   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   : 2145                                        
 3rd Qu.: 2199                                        
 Max.   :10410                                        

     score      
 Min.   : 0.00  
 1st Qu.: 4.00  
 Median : 7.00  
 Mean   : 8.33  
 3rd Qu.:12.00  
 Max.   :27.00  
 NA's   :1
```

I tried `lubridate` on the `assigned` column but it overwrote all the values to NA.

```
library(lubridate)
data_subset$assigned <- mdy(data_subset$assigned)


       id assigned completed score
1:     54     <NA>  11/10/16     0
2:     54     <NA>  11/21/16     7
3:     54     <NA>   1/26/17    11
```

I am looking for a way to make `assigned` and `completed` be read as dates--whether it happens during the .csv import, or through data manipulation after it's already in R.

Comment: I can't replicate this - `data_subset$assigned <- mdy(data_subset$assigned)` works just fine.

Comment: Reproducible code with `mdy` working: `data_subset <- data.frame(id = c(54L, 54L, 54L), assigned = c("11/10/16", 
"11/21/16", "1/26/17"), completed = c("11/10/16", "11/21/16", 
"1/26/17"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE); data_subset$assigned <- lubridate::mdy(data_subset$assigned); data_subset`

Comment: If you use RStudio, try the "Import Dataset" link in the Environment pane. It allows you to preview the data, change column type (by clicking in the preview column header), troubleshoot issues and generate code for reuse later.

Comment: I have tried to import in RStudio and change column type (thanks for the great tip!), and as soon as I change it to "date", it over-writes it with NAs, just like what happened with Lubridate. Any ideas for what about this data that's causing this to happen?

Comment: When you change the column to "date" does it prompt you "Please enter format string"?  If so... what format do you enter? One thought is you have the format incorrect. A second thought is that you your dates may have leading or trailing spaces (e.g., " 11/21/16" or "11/21/26 ").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manipulation after importing approach:**

```
data_subset$assigned <- as.Date(data_subset$assigned,'%m/%d/%y') # This uses base R
data_subset$completed <- as.Date(data_subset$completed,'%m/%d/%y') # The '%/m/%d/%y' specifies the format of your date
```

Sidenote: I have been working on a similar problem and `lubridate` has been doing weird things lately. I suspect the reason may be in part to the version of R. `lubridate` seems to work better on R 3.3.3 than on r-microsoft 3.3.3. I have had certain functions from the package missing on the r-mircosoft distribution. Perhaps some underlying function is missing which is causing everything to go to NA. Again this is just speculation, but maybe it leads to an answer.